# why I have two different result when I execute this javascript closure code

Tags: javascript, closures

my code :

```
var n;
function f(){
   var v = "kevin";
   n = function(){
      return v;
   }
}
```

execute in FireBug:
n();
the result is "kevin"

execute in Chrome & IE9:

document.writeln(n);   ======>show "undefine"
document.writeln(n()); ======>show nothing

I want to know what exactly the brows doing when execute the code.
Thanks.

That code is a demo of the book "Object Oriented JavaScript", Chapter 3, Closure 2#

Comment: `f()` must be called before `n` is set to a function.

Comment: n should be unassigned until f() is executed. Possibly bug in FireBug. f(); alert(n()); is working fine.

Comment: this code should not return anything at all.

Comment: You probably ran it once in Firebug with `f()`, then removed `f()` before testing in Chrome. After you've run it the first time, you've created a global `n` variable, so if you then remove the `f()` call, `n` still exists. [Run your code in `jsFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/YUcGc/1/) instead of the console to get a clean environment each time you run it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `n` is not given a value (i.e., is not assigned to that function) until the function `f()` has been executed - which doesn't happen in the code you show.

So `document.writeln(n);` should show "undefined", while `document.writeln(n());` should be an error since n is not a function.

I don't know why it works in FireBug - have you already executed `f()` when you try it?

Comment: Executing `f()` should return undefined because f doesn't explicitly return a value. But after you execute `f()` you should then be able to execute `n()` and get back "kevin".